# teradata updating a table in a cost effective manner

Tags: teradata

I have a table that has sequence numbers. Its a very big table 16 million rows give or take. The table has a key and it has events that happen to that key. Every time the key changes the seq_nums restarts in theory.

In the original table I had there was a timestamp associated with each event. In order to get the duration of the event i created a lag column and subtracted the lag column from the time stamp of the current event giving us the duration. This duration is called `time_in_minutes` in the table below

The new table has a number of properties

- Each key in this case is a car wash with each event being assigned a category so on line 3 the car was submitted to a drying procedure for 45 mins
- The second line which contains 23 mins, isn't actually 23 mins for the wash, it took the machine 23 minutes to power up
- In ID number 144 the record for the powering up of the machine is missing. This seems to be prevalent in the data set

  ```
  key     Event       time in mins    seq_num
  1       Start           0                 1
  1       Wash            23                2
  1       Dry             45                3
  1       Wash            56                4
  1       Wash            78                5
  1       Boil            20                6
  1       ShutDown        11                7
  2       Start           0                 1
  2       Wash            11                2
  2       Dry             12                3
  -------------------------------------------
  144     Wash            0                 1
  144     Wash            11                2
  144     Dry             12                3
  ```

I would like to move the `time_in_mins` to the seq_num 1 if is an `Event` of type *Start* in the previous record. So when we aggregate this later the minutes will be properly assigned to starting up

I could try and update the table by creating a new column again with another lag for `time_in_mins` this time but this seems to be quite expensive
Does anyone know of a clever way of doing this?

**Edit** 14/10/2016

The final output for the customer is like below albeit slightly out of order

```
key event       total minutes
1   Start       23
1   Boil        20
1   Dry         45
1   Wash        134
1   ShutDown    11
2   Start       11
2   Dry         12
2   Wash        0
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What if there's only sequence number 1, but no 2?

Comment: This is a very good question and raises another one i hadn't thought of, what if the sequence number 1 has a value in it other than zero. I will update the question to reflect this

Comment: Do you really want to Update the table or just do the calculation within a Select? What's your Teradata release? Can you add the expected result?  Btw, 16 million rows is not a big table :)

Comment: Hi @dnoeth. The 16 million rows is a volatile table within my spool space but you are probably right in the grand scheme of things :). he size is for one month, but they want to run the analysis for 12. I would be happy to do it in the select as that will be the answer used by the customer...I'll update the question now with the final outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will switch 1st and 2nd value based on your description, resulting in a single STAT-step in Explain:

```
SELECT key, seq_num, event, 
   CASE
     WHEN seq_num = 1
      AND Event = 'Start'
       THEN Min(CASE WHEN seq_num = 2 THEN time_in_mins ELSE 0 END) 
            Over (PARTITION BY key)
     WHEN seq_num = 2
      AND Min(CASE WHEN seq_num = 1 THEN Event END)
          Over (PARTITION BY key) = 'Start' THEN 0 
        ELSE time_in_mins 
   END AS new_time_in_mins
FROM tab
```

Now you can do the sum.

But it might be possible to include the logic in your previous step when you create the Voltile Table, can you add this Select, too?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth, this was exactly what i was looking for. Thank you so much for your help